# Temas, styles e support Library android

Tags: android, android-layout, app-compat-v7

Olá desde que comecei a trabalhar com desenvolvimento Android, sempre tive muita dificuldade em entender como funciona a parte de Temas, estilos e *libs* de *support* do Android, sempre tenho muita dificuldade por exemplo a estilizar um `EditText` ou um `RatingBar`. 
Por exemplo agora pouco estava estilizando um `RatingBar` onde eu tinha no meu tema o seguinte item:

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
    parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:ratingBarStyle">@style/customRatingBar</item>

<style name="customRatingBar" parent="android:Widget.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/ratingbar_full_holo_dark</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/ratingbar_full_holo_dark</item>
</style>
```

Na API 23 funcionou tranquilamente, porém para que funcionasse em APIS menores eu tive que por o seguinte código no style-v11

```
  <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"  parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:ratingBarStyle">@style/customRatingBar</item>
    <item name="ratingBarStyle">@style/customRatingBar</item>
</style>
```

O que eu quero entender é, qual a diferença de por o `android`: e sem o `android:` no item?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esses atributos só estão disponíveis a partir da *API level 21*. Para que possam ser usados em versões anteriores teremos que recorrer àqueles que são definidos na *appCompat api*.

Para que esses *styles/themes* seja aplicados tanto a aplicação corra em dispositivos pré ou corra em dispositivos pós *API level 21* terá de os definir duas vezes, uma usando o prefixo `android:` e outra sem o prefixo.

O prefixo `android:` refere-se ao nome da *package* onde o *style* está definido e deve ser usado para o caso da *API level 21*(ou superior, aquela a que `compileSdkVersion` se refere).
Não usando o prefixo está a referir-se aos *styles/themes* definidos na *appCompat api*.

O procedimento a seguir é o seguinte:

- Defina um tema herdado de `Theme.AppCompat`<sup>(1)</sup> em `res/values/styles.xml`.
- Defina um tema com o mesmo nome herdado do tema do Material em `res/values-v21/styles.xml`.
- Defina esse tema como o tema do seu aplicativo no arquivo de manifesto.
- No `res/values/styles.xml` **não use** o prefixo `android:` quando se referir a atributos apenas existentes após a *API level 21*.
- Utilize `res/values-v21/styles.xml` para definir *styles/themes* que **não** sejam compatíveis com as versões pré *API level 21*, use sempre o prefixo `android:`

Para mais informação veja a [documentação](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/material/compatibility.html).

<sub>(1) Após AppCompat v21.1.1 terá de herdar de `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` ou `Theme.AppCompat.Dark.NoActionBar` e terá de usar *Toolbar* em vez de *ActionBar*</sub>

Comment: Excelente explicação :)