# You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity

Tags: android, style

Estou tendo esse problema quando rodo meu app em um android 4.4. Já passei o dia todo procurando soluções, mas nada funciona e eu não consigo encontrar erros em meu código. Agradeço desde já qualquer ajuda!

[image: Exception]

style.xml:

```
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

v21\style.xml:

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

    <!--<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>-->
    <!--faz o drawer aparecer por baixo do status-->
    <!--<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>-->

    <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/AppTheme.DialogStyle</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AppTheme.DialogStyle</item>

    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.DialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="false"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"

    <activity
        android:name=".controller.activitys.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>...
```

Comment: Veja se esta [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/107138/2541) resolve.

Comment: De certa forma o seu comentário me ajudou a encontrar a solução. Obrigado! A solução foi espelhar os 2 arquivos style.xml e colocar as características únicas da api 21+ apenas no v21/style.xml

Answer (score 0):

No Lugar de:

```
<activity
        android:name=".controller.activitys.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
```

Você deve colocar:

```
<activity
        android:name=".controller.activitys.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
```

Ai você tira a ActionBar via código se preferir.

Comment: A sua solução acabou me dando mais problemas, pois o AppTheme.NoAtionBar contém as configurações da activity e também com problemas pra usar o toolbar contido na activity